# How to fix 'getter isn't defined for class' error in Dart?

Tags: angular, dart, angular-dart

My Angular Dart App does not compile. I am new to Angular Dart and I don't understand what the problem is.

This is the BookListComponent:

```dart
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';

import '../book.dart';

@Component(
  selector: 'book-list',
  styleUrls: ['book_list_component.css'],
  templateUrl: 'book_list_component.html',
  directives: [NgFor],
)
class BookListComponent {
  List<Book> books = [
    new Book('Test 1'),
    new Book('Test 2'),
    new Book('Test 3')
  ];
}
```

This is the BookListComponent template:

```html
<ul>
  <li ngFor="let book of books">{{ book.title }}</li>
</ul>
```

This is the Book class

```dart
class Book {
  String title;

  Book(this.title);
}
```

When compiling this error occures: `[error] The getter 'book' isn't defined for the class 'BookListComponent'. (package:bookshelf/src/book_list/book_list_component.template.dart)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template is wrong, the `ngFor` is missing the leading star.

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let book of books">{{ book.title }}</li>
</ul>
```

Also change the `Book` class as follows.

```
class Book {
  String title;
  Book(String title) {
    this.title = title;  
  }
}
```